# Exact Matching with r MatchIt with ratio 1:4

Tags: methods, match, exact-match

I would like to run an exact match by state but at the same time I would like a ratio of 1 to 4 case:control. Will the following code do the trick? I understand method=exact won't work since that method does not support the ratio parameter. If yes, how do I check if matching is exact? If not, how can I fix my code? I have plenty of data (255 cases & 7500 control so exact shouldn't be a problem at all)

Thank you!

```
exact_match <- matchit(case ~ state , ratio = 4,  data = case_crude, exact="statabbr")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to throw out any units that are more than the 4th exact match. For example, if 5 control units resemble your treated unit, why would you only want to retain 4 of them?

Otherwise, that code should work to do what you want. It performs 4:1 nearest neighbor matching on a propensity score estimated with `state` as the sole predictor with exact matching on `statabbr`.

To check if exact matching was successful, check balance using `summary()`. You should see that the mean differences are 0 and the pair distance are also 0 (i.e., implying that within each pair, the values of `statabbr` are identical.